# Nose tip detection

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, itk

I would like to know if there are any argorithms in ITK or OpenCV to detect nose tip? 
I am programming in C++ and so far have application that uses ABS files to display 3D scans of faces. Now I would like to perform nose tip detection in 2D images. Thank You all for help.

Comment: just read you want 2d detection. opencv has a built-in nose classifier under \data\haarcascades\.. tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier

Comment: Ok, I will analize it :D thanks!

Comment: Check out this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4573) that may help you.

Comment: I mentioned that and this : http://ijcsi.org/papers/7-4-4-1-9.pdf before and erased as he was looking for 2d solutions..